# Mapbox: iOS : Calculate remaining Polyline points from location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapbox

I'm developing one navigation application, I want to calculate the remaining polyline left. I already drawn the route over the map. As user start navigation, I want to update the remaining polyline points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Turf framework for this case.

```
import Turf

let stepPoints = LineString(step.coordinates)
let remainingPoints = stepPoints.sliced(from: location, to: nil)
```